# what type of data we can store in NSIndexPath object

Tags: ios, objective-c

As we can store a collection of charecters in a NSString object and a key,value pair in a NSDictionary object which type of data we can hold in NSIndexpath object

Answer (score 2):

The `NSIndexPath` class represents the path to a specific node in a tree of nested array collections. This path is known as an index path.

Each index in an index path represents the index into an array of children from one node in the tree to another, deeper, node. For example, the `index path 1.4.3.2` specifies the path in below figure
[image]

for more info https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/

Answer (score 0):

**NSIndexpath** holds typically **integer** values referred to as *index values*. These index values are wrapped up in the **NSIndexPath** object in some logical way so as they can be interpreted accordingly.

Example could be you require a multi-dimensional array and need to keep track of the index path to a particular element.

For iOS refer to [NSIndexPath UIKit Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSIndexPath/section)

Answer (score 0):

`NSIndexPath` holds an ordered list of integers referring a path through a tree.

```
0 entry
  0 subentry 1
  1 subentry 2
1 another entry
  0 subentry of another entry
    0 subsubentry
    1 another subsubentry
  1 another subentry of another entry
```

I. e. "another subsubentry" has the path 1.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

We use NSIndexPath most commonly in UITableView methods to get section number and row number of current or selected index.If we go as an example of UITableView case it holds all section numbers in an array and holds  all rows in different arrays based on number of items in section array. each section has sub array that contains rows of that section.

For more have a look at [NSIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/)